# Capturar dados do Json (Array) e colocar no HTML

Tags: javascript

Galera, estou com uma dificuldade em capturar os itens dentro de um objeto no **Json**.

Segue o código abaixo para exemplificar.

```
 var tipos = [
    {
        "code": "258",
        "label": "Sapatos"
    },
    {
        "code": "547",
        "label": "Kits"
    },
    {
        "code": "1213",
        "label": "Whey Protein"
    },
    {
        "code": "3110",
        "label": "Bolas"
    },
    {
        "code": "4316",
        "label": "Camisas de Time"
    },
    {
        "code": "1251",
        "label": "Cuecas"
    }];
```

console.log(tipos)

Eu consigo capturar todo array dando o console.log()

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que eu preciso associar isso no html, tipo , criar um botão (input) onde o usuário irá colar somente o nome dos tipos de produtos e irá retornar o código, ou vice e versa.

Seria mais ou menos assim

O usuário digita *Bolas* e deverá retornar  `{"code": "3110", "label": "Bolas"}`,
Se ele digitar *Bolas, Kits*, deverá retornar `{"code": "3110", "label": "Bolas"},  {"code": "547","label": "Kits"}`

Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Cara, botão não é digitável, é um elemento para receber click.

Comment: Na verdade eu me expressei mal, não seria botão , seria uma caixa de texto/pesquisa.

Comment: Utilize [**Array.filter**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=array.filter) para filtrar os elementos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar `.filter()` depois de fazer um `.split()` no que foi digitado, considerando que o texto digitado pode ser separado por vírgula, conforme informado na pergunta (ex.: Kits, Bolas).

Também utilizei um `.map()` para fazer um `.trim()` (eliminar espaços nas bordas) e utilizei `.toLowerCase()` para deixar *case insensitive* (irá encontrar maiúsculas ou minúsculas) tornando mais flexível a busca.

```js
var tipos = [ { "code": "258", "label": "Sapatos" }, { "code": "547", "label": "Kits" }, { "code": "1213", "label": "Whey Protein" }, { "code": "3110", "label": "Bolas" }, { "code": "4316", "label": "Camisas de Time" }, { "code": "1251", "label": "Cuecas" }];

function buscar(){
   var texto = document.body.querySelector("#texto").value;
   
   // converte em array e elimina espaços indesejados nas bordas
   // e converte para minúsculo, pare evitar o case sensitive
   var texto_array = texto.split(",").map(function(i){
      return i.trim().toLowerCase();
   });
   
   var resultado = tipos.filter(function(e){
      return ~texto_array.indexOf(e.label.toLowerCase());
   });
   
   // imprimir numa div
   var res = document.body.querySelector("#resultado");
   res.innerHTML = '';
   for(var item of resultado){
      res.innerHTML += "<strong>Código:</strong> "+item.code
      +"<br><strong>Tipo:</strong> "+item.label+"<br><br>";
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="resultado">
</div>
Digite o que quer buscar:
<br>
<input type="text" id="texto" value="Kits, bolas,camisas de Time">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="buscar()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, não sei se eu entendi bem, se interpretei errado, perdoe-me, mas pelo visto, o quê procura é um sistema do tipo "autocomplete"?

Eu utilizei a biblioteca **easy-autocomplete.js**. Li a documentação e adaptei um dos exemplo do próprio site abaixo. Veja se é isto que procura, amigo.

```js
var options = {
 data: [{"name": "Bolas", "code": "STZ998"}, {"name": "Sapatos", "code": "CTX456"}],

getValue: "name",

 template: {
  type: "description",
  fields: {
   description: "code"
  }
 }

};

$("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.js"></script>

Digite "Bolas" ou "Sapatos"
<input id="provider-json" placeholder="Digite..." />
```

**Fonte:** http://easyautocomplete.com